# Priority Queue: If two objects have same priority, how do I determine which to extract?

Tags: python, queue, priority-queue

Basically, no counter is allowed. No iterables (arrays, dictionaries, etc.) allowed either to store insertion. There are two linked lists: one storing odd insertions and even insertions. Each node has the priority, and the object. Is there any pattern you can find? Or is this impossible?

Edit: sorry for not mentioning, we need to extract the first one that was inserted.

Comment: The qustion in your title is about which item to choose when they have the same priority, in your text you are asking about finding a pattern (where?). Also I am not quite sure what your setup looks like. Can you elaborate and make clear what your question is?

Comment: Well, which do you want to extract in such a case? Ask yourself that, come to a conclusion, and either implement it if you can or tell us about it.

Comment: What, exactly, are you asking? The answer to the question in the title is "whichever one you want." As for the remaining text, it's not at all clear what the problem is, or what you're asking. Pattern to what? Edit your question and add more detail.

Comment: Then store the time of insertion as well as the priority, and break priority ties by time.  End of problem.

Comment: Is there any way I can do that without making it an instance variable?

Comment: You could put the prioritized object in a wrapper object which also stores the time, but time will have to be stored somewhere.

Comment: You're still not giving us enough information. You say that there are two linked lists. Do those lists represent the priority queue in the order in which the nodes were inserted? Edit your question and *give an example*. We can't help you if you don't give us pertinent information. We shouldn't have to drag the information out of you.

Answer (score 0):

Since all items are arranged in a prioritised manner, just extract them in the way they come out...as it is a queue. Or you could apply more conditions on how you would like to arrange the items with same priorities among themselves.